# How do I use valid Alloy.Globals variables in values in Appcelerator App Designer

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I have found a problem while using **Appcelerator App Designer** with regards to the use of **Titanium SDK constants** and **Alloy.Globals** as values.

In example, I have a value in alloy.js

```
Alloy.Globals.myColors = {
    very_light: "#edf5fc",
    light: "#c7e3ff",
    mid: "#0066CB",
    dark: "#06426D"
};
```

So in my tss file I can have

```
backgroundColor: Alloy.Globals.myColors.light
```

This works perfectly.

If I use **Appcelerator App Designer** to modify any part of the layout it changes the tss value to a string, basically breaking it in alloy. e.g.:

```
backgroundColor: "Alloy.Globals.myColors.light"
```

This behavior also works for Ti Constants that start with *Titanium* instead of *Ti*. Unfortunately **Appcelerator App Designer** has there old *Titanium.UI* constants in the dropdowns instead of the *Ti.UI* constants.

For the Titanium constants I know that if I modify it in the TSS file that future modification to the design using the app designer won't break it. I don't know how to avoid the problem with **Alloy.Globals** variables though.

Any suggestions?

[EDIT]
You can find the [Appcelerator JIRA Ticket here](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-3445)

Comment: This is excellent feedback on this beta product. Thanks for that! Could you check if these are known issues at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If some are not, please create tickets, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: I could not find anything on Jira related to this issue so I have submitted it on this [link](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-3445)

Comment: That ticket link no longer works. One day I got notification of it being edited by Sharif AbuDarda and now its gone. I tried to get more info from the jira guys, but no response after 9 days. The email seems now to link to [this](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23238) but I have no permissions to view it

Comment: We've moved the ticket to the Gui Builder project which unfortunately is private. I'll see if we can make it (or this ticket) public.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Fokke. At least I know there are still eyes on the project.

Comment: There was finally some work on this. Unfortunately I can no longer ue it. Appcelerator decided the feature was too cool for indie developers and now made it available only to pro and higher subscribers. Very disappointing.